# Auto create Excel sheets from Array values

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am relatively new to vba. I have used VB a long time ago so I derive a lot of info from that experience. Though now I'm facing a harder task and I don't quite know how to do it.

I have got a data sheet with in column E software version information (ie "3.1.1", "3.1.2" and so on). I have created a for loop the searches through E. In this for there are several if statements like this one:

```
If Cells(r, Columns("E").Column).Value = "3.1.2" Then 'find criteria

            'Copy the current row
            Rows(r).Select
            Selection.Copy

            'Switch to the sprint where you want to paste it & paste
            Sheets("Sprint 2").Select
            Rows(sprint2).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste

            sprint2 = sprint2 + 1 'next row

            'Switch back to backlog & continue to search for criteria
            Sheets("Backlog").Select
ElseIf...
```

This is working fine for me, except that I need to create the sheets before running the macro. What I would like to do is:

1. Search through column E
2. Fill an array with all *unique* values in Column E*[edit]
3. Create a sheet for every value in the Array

I would love to hear what you guys think.

Comment: Do you mean unique values in column E? Have you already created an array?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean. And no i have not yet made or filled the Array since my knowledge of Arrays is very limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps that helps:

```
Sub ColumnE()
Dim colE As Long, r As Long, c As Object, exists As Boolean
Dim values As Collection, i As Long
Set values = New Collection
colE = Columns("E").Column
r = Cells(Rows.Count, colE).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To r ' step 1: loop through column E
    exists = False
    For Each c In values ' step 2: look in collection if the element was already inserted
        If c = Cells(i, colE) Then
            exists = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next c
    If Not exists Then values.Add Cells(i, colE)
Next i
For Each c In values ' step 3: add a sheet for every value in collection
    Worksheets.Add  ' WARNING: you should test, if there already is a sheet with that name
    ActiveSheet.name = c
Next c
End Sub
```

I like to use collections more than arrays in vba, because i can dynamically add new elements without resizing. (but it depends on the situation...)

Comment: what command should I now use to call the sheet? In other words: `Sheets("Sprint 2").Select` what should I change that to? `Sheets(c).Select` and `Sheets("c").Select` both won't work.

Comment: Try `Sheets(CStr(c)).Activate`. (but `c` is only defined in the `for each` loop.