# Name Sheets Based on Array Value Then Copy Rows From Range With Same Value as Sheet Name

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table that I need to do the following with:

1. Get the range of the fk_keyword column
2. Loop through the range and identify only unique values
3. Loop through the unique values and create sheets with the name of the unique values
4. Loop through the original range (fk_keyword) and copy the entire row to the sheet with the matching name

For example: If the value found in fk_keyword matches the name of a sheet, then for all the cells that meet the same criteria, their entire row must be copied to that sheet.

I found a few similar questions, however, they all seem to be slightly different to my query, in that I am having different issues..

The closest match to my question I found is here:

[VBA- search sheet name from range.. then copy from range sheet, paste transpose into that sheetname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46335024/vba-search-sheet-name-from-range-then-copy-from-range-sheet-paste-transpose)

Even though I found this, I am not using the code in this example.

Instead, I have received the help up to this point from these links:

**Copy Entire Row to New Sheet:**

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3723-excel-move-row-to-another-sheet-based-on-cell-value.html

**Create Sheets from Excel Cell Value:**

[Auto create Excel sheets from Array values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17167412/auto-create-excel-sheets-from-array-values)

**Remove Duplicates from Array:**

https://wellsr.com/vba/2017/excel/vba-remove-duplicates-from-array/

So here is the code I have at the moment:

*Functions:*

**move_Data_To_Sheet**

```
Function move_Data_To_Sheet(myArray As Variant)

    'Dim variables
    Dim xRg As Range, xCell
    Dim I As Long, J, K, Counter
    Dim tmpltWkbk As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet

    'Set variables
    Set xRg = find_Header("fk_keyword")
    Set tmpltWkbk = Workbooks("New DB.xlsm")
    Set ws1 = tmpltWkbk.Sheets("TableSheet")

    'Get the row count of the primary sheet
    I = ws1.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Counter = 0

    'loop through each element in my array
    For Each c In myArray

        'Check that that element is not empty
        If c <> "" Then

            'Add a new sheet after the active sheet
            Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet

            'Name the new sheet the same as the current element name in the array
            ActiveSheet.Name = c

            'Get the row count of the new sheet
            J = Worksheets(c).UsedRange.Rows.Count

            'Check if the value is 1
            If J = 1 Then

               'Check if the value is 0
               If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets(c).UsedRange) = 0 Then

                'J is actually empty
                J = 0

               End If

            End If

            'Loop through the specific range (fk_keyword) on the primary sheet
            For K = 1 To xRg.Count

                'Check if the element matches the current element in the first array
                If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = c Then

                    'Copy the entire row from the primary sheet to the newly added sheet
                    xRg(K).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets(c).Range("A" & J + 1)

                    'Delete the row from the primary sheet
                    xRg(K).EntireRow.Delete

                    'Increment J
                    J = J + 1

                    'Increment the counter
                    Counter = Counter + 1

                End If

            'Next element in the array
            Next

        End If

    'Next element in the array
    Next c

End Function
```

Below is the issue I am experiencing.

When the data is copied to the new sheets based on the Cell value (KW ID), it seems to only copy some of the data and not all of it.

For Example, in the image below are the totals for the numeric values found under the **fk_keyword** column in my sheet. These numeric values are **KW ID's** and the totals are how many times they appear in the **fk_keyword** column.

[image]

Now when I copy the data to the new sheets, instead of having all the data copied, it will copy something like this:

- For KW ID 5: 11 Rows
- For KW ID 9: 15 Rows
- For KW ID 10: 13 Rows

And so on. But not a single KW ID, with all its rows were copied and I cannot understand why.

Comment: I believe you should have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: A note on the errors you identified: the `arrCol` variable is a collection. I don't believe a collection lets you check what values already exist in it (and some entries end up read-only, data type dependent). An informative link on collections: https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-collections/  A link on Dictionaries (which have an `.Exists` method, but require either a reference or late-binding): https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/

Comment: @peakpeak Thank you for the reply. I do apologize for the long post, I just don't know how to shorten it.. If I leave out functions, then I will surely get asked to see the code. And on numerous posts I have been asked about removing `On Error Resume Next` so I just included it in the post.

Comment: @Mistella Thank you for the reply, I will read up on the links provided and possibly look into changing the collection to a dictionary instead :)

Comment: @peakpeak Okay, I have shortened it to only the function that does the copying now. :)

Comment: It sounds like this would help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49008817/filtering-multiple-criteria-into-separate-worksheets